# Wrong icon displayed in windows form title bar

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to change the icon in the top-left corner of the title bar in a windows form. It changes in the designer but not when the application runs in release/debug modes. The icon does not update when I directly run the application from the folder either. I have windows 8

I have tried the following:

1. Form -> Properties-> Icon - Set the icon. At this point, it shows up in the designer.
2. Added the new icon as an icon (.ico) file into the Resources.resx. This points to the location where the icon file is present
3. NewLogo.ico -> Properties-> Copy to output directory - tried to set this to both copy if newer/copy always
4. Project->Properties->Application - Under Icon and manifest, changed the Icon and its location to point to where the new icon is. The new icon shows up in the Icon and manifest box
5. Project->Properties->Debug - Unchecked 'Enable the Visual Studio hosting process'
6. Cleared the icon cache
7. Restarted my system
8. Deleted the old icon file from everywhere on my system
9. Killed and restarted explorer.exe
10. The designer code that picks up the icon is as follows:

    ```
    this.Icon = ((System.Drawing.Icon)(resources.GetObject("$this.Icon")));
    ```

Tried changing it to

```
    this.Icon = Properties.Resources.NewLogo
```

After all this, the old icon still shows up when I run the application
How do I fix this?

Thanks,

Comment: have you done a rebuild?

Comment: Google "windows reset icon cache".

Comment: Daniel A. White - Yes, of course, after each of the change that I listed above

Comment: Hans Passant - Thanks, ill try that

Answer (score 1):

Looks like not reproducible glitch. What I would do is:

- create new form
- set the desired icon
- copy paste the code from the old one

Please let us know if this worked.

Comment: Thanks :) this is my last resort. The icon works fine for the other forms in this project